# No suitable driver found error in Java/Maven project

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/exp_man

It shows this error in my Java with Maven application project even after I have added and installed the MySQL connector jar file in the dependency tab. When I deleted the dependency it shows `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`
I tried reinstalling NetBeans, still it shows the same error.

What do I do?

Comment: Are you referring to [this connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)? By the way, how is your question related to _Swing_?

Comment: Yes. I am making a desktop application in java with mysql as database interface.

Comment: You have a typo in your URL, it should be `jdbc:mysql://...`, so **one** colon after `jdbc`, not two.

Comment: All JDBC database drivers are dynamically discovered via the Java SPI (Service Provider Interface). Via the URL part `jdbc:mysql:`. So if the URL is wrong it will not find the driver. You can see the working in the driver jar, a zip with path: META-INF/services/...